# What is the difference between initial and instance in django formset?

Tags: python, django, formset

What is the difference between initial and instance in django formset?

When to use which?

What should I use to show the prepopulated data in an invalid form in the following case:

```
formset= FormSet(initial=[{'a':list.b} for list in listslist])
if request.method =='post':
    formset = FormSet(request.post, ---instance/initial? ---)
```

Comment: read the docs. `instance` is for `ModelForm` which modify an instance of a model, `initial` is for regular forms

Comment: Thank you, I did and haven't found an answer to my question. how do I set initials for non-model forms? initial doesn't work

Comment: maybe post your actual code, you are clearly doing something wrong

Answer (score 2):

`initial` is to set defaults for new forms.

`instances` is to set models instances you use as initial models, which will be populated with entered data. You can use this attribute to **edit your model instances**.

Comment: but then how do I set initials for non-model forms? initial doesn't work

Comment: `initial` is made to be initials for any form. At least documentation and my experience says that, lol. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-initial-data-with-a-formset